# GO type cast and assignment using interfaces

Tags: go, pointers, casting

I can't get my head around type casting using interfaces.

There is an example for setting value using pointers:

```
func main() {
    a := &A{}
    
    cast(a, "BBB")

    fmt.Println(a.s)
}

type A struct {
    s string
}

func cast(a *A, b interface{}) {
    a.s = b.(string)
}
```

The output of this program will print `BBB`.

Now my problem is that what if I want to set more than string? I imagine that I want to do something like this:

```
func main() {
    a := &A{}
    
    cast(&(a.s), "BBB")

    fmt.Println(a.s)

}

type A struct {
    s string
}

func cast(a interface{}, b interface{}) {
    // Here could be type switch to determine what kind of type I want to cast to, but for know string is enough...
    a = b.(string)
}
```

And this code's output is an empty string... Could anyone help me to understand what I've been doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second program assigns to local variable `a`, not to the caller's variable `a`.

You must dereference the pointer to assign to the caller's value. To do, that you need a pointer type. Use a type assertion to get the pointer type:

```
func cast(a interface{}, b interface{}) {
    *a.(*string) = b.(string)
}
```